# Splash Screen, playing an mp4

Tags: android, video

I have to play a video at the launching of my application. 
I want it to be local, but it's too big to be translated to raw (11 sec), i've got to keep my app the lighter possible. And because it's a splashscreen, i don't need media controller.

I wonder what is the best way to do so, if I'm right, VideoView can't understand direct mp4.
Does anybody have done so ?

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity{
    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player_layout);


        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_player_video_view);
//      mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.splash));
//      myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();

    }
}
```

EDIT : with media player, it stays in error state

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splash);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.start();
```

Comment: Why is size a problem? Just put it in the expand project if needed. If size is a really big problem, you shouldn't have a video splash.

Comment: I wanted to say that i didn't want to translate it to raw, i know that i will put it in my project but I thought that mp4 wasn't red by VideoViews

Comment: Sorry can't help you with which format it supports.

Answer (score 3):

```
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.splash));
```

replace the above line by below and try..

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName()+"/raw/splash";
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
myVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
```

Comment: hello, thx for that and sorry for the delay, but from which object the method getDataSource comes from ?

Comment: just try commenting that line

Comment: it does not work when I comment it

Comment: nop i'm sorry, but it works fine on the iPhone app, I don't think there is anything wrong with it, I'm trying something with mediaPlayer now, i add it in my post

Comment: i too use mp4 file as splash in my app

Comment: could you share the way you're doing so ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html